# Inventory UI acting strange in updating amounts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

So I have an item class, an inventory class and the UIController scripts. When the player goes over the item on the field the player should have the item added to the inventory, if he/she has the item it should increase the amount by one.

The issue I'm having is the numbers on the UI are random and sometimes items add amounts other times they just use a new slot. I have added the three scripts I mentioned above.

```
public Item() 
{
    amount = 0;
}

public int GetItemAmount() 
{
    return amount;
}

public void IncreaseAmount(int amt) 
{
    amount += amt;
}    

public void SpawnItem() 
{
    Instantiate(prefab);
}
```

```
public Inventory() 
{
    inventory = new List<Item>();
}
    
    
// Add item to inventory. if item is already in inventory, increase amount.
public void AddItem(Item item) 
{    
    if (inventory.Count == 0)
    {
        inventory.Add(item);
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GetInventory().Count; i++)
        {
            if (this.inventory[i] == item)
            {
                inventory[i].IncreaseAmount(1);
                break;
            }
            else
            {    
                 inventory.Add(item);                        
            }
            break;
         }  
     }
}
```

```
void Start()
{
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<PlayerController>();
    inventoryItems = CreateInventoryItemUI(itemSlotImage);
}

private void Update()
{
    var playerItems = player.inventory.GetInventory();

    for (int i = 0; i <= playerItems.Count ; i++)
    {
        //Debug.Log("The value of i is : " + i);
        if (playerItems[i] != null)
        {
            inventoryItems[i].GetComponentInChildren<Image>().sprite = playerItems[i].imageIcon;
            var amountUI = inventoryItems[i].transform.Find("ItemSlotAmount").GetComponent<Text>();
            amountUI.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            amountUI.text = playerItems[i].GetItemAmount().ToString();
            Debug.Log("The items being added will be: " + amountUI.text);
            inventoryItems[i].gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
```

I think I just another set of eyes. I debugged and checked reference of the increase amount method and it's only used in the inventory script.

Any ideas would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking if the added Item is exactly the same object as one in the list, as in the same reference. I'm assuming this is probably not what you want, please post the part of the code calling AddItem otherwise.

Two suggestions:

First, add an Id property to Item and compare if the item being added has the same Id, instead of comparing the references.

Second, this would probably be cleaner and more efficient if you used a Dictionary instead of a List for storing the items. Give it a try!

Comment: I changed everything to a dictionary and it's much easier to keep track of things. Issue has now been resolved. Thank you!